# Storing values shown on the terminal screen

Tags: command-line, scripts

I use a software called Gromacs. I use the command:

```
g_bar -f md*.xvg -o -oi -oh
```

to calculate and print my results in the terminal. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I want to store the DG Values in different variables or in an array.These results always start with Lambda. I want to store DG values because I am writing a program, which prints information related to for all the lambda ranges.

So my program prints

```
    Lambda_Range = 0-0.05  distance= XXX   force = XXX
```

I also want to Print DG values with that

```
    Lambda_Range = 0-0.05  distance= XXX   force = XXX    DG = XXX
```

Only idea I can think is that if I am able to somehow store DG values in array or in variables. I guess then I can achieve what I want.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: That depends on what your goal is.

Comment: If you told us what you want to do with those variables after storing them, it would make the whole thing easier to answer. And if you want to share terminal outputs, please rather copy them and paste them here using code formatting (**`{}`**-button) instead of using screenshots. Thank you!

Comment: I guess you want the to store the first `0.00 +/- 0.00` as  the first element of the array, the second `-0.00 +/- 0.00` as the second element of the array, the third `0.00 +/- 0.00` as the third element of the array and so on excluding the total, is that correct? Do all the lines that contain the `DG` values always start with `lambda`? Are the separators all space? Please [edit] your question and add these informations, possibly adding the output of the terminal formatted as Byte Commander suggested

Comment: You could store all the stdout from that program, or any program, into a variable with a command like `variable=$( command )` and piping stdout through programs like grep, cut, or sed or awk first you can pick out just the parts you want. Just using sed or awk can do an awful lot too. See `man bash` & `man sed` & `man awk` , basically `man [anything]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may process the output using `sed` and use `bash`'s `mapfile` builtin to read the output into an array:

```
mapfile -t a < <(g_bar -f md*.xvg -o -oi -oh | sed '/lambda/s/.*DG *//')
```

- `-t`: removes the trailing newline from each line of input before reading it into the array
- `a`: the name of the array
- `< <(g_bar -f md*.xvg -o -oi -oh | sed '/lambda/s/.*DG *//')`: redirects the output of the process substitution running `g_bar -f md*.xvg -o -oi -oh | sed '/lambda/s/.*DG *//'` to `mapfile`'s `stdin`

This way each result will be stored in the array `$a`.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/tmp$ cat infile
lambda 0.000 - 0.000, DG -0.00 +/- 0.00
lambda 0.000 - 0.000, DG  0.01 +/- 0.09
lambda 0.000 - 0.000, DG -0.02 +/- 0.08
lambda 0.000 - 0.000, DG  0.03 +/- 0.07
lambda 0.000 - 0.000, DG -0.04 +/- 0.06
lambda 0.000 - 0.000, DG  0.05 +/- 0.05
lambda 0.000 - 0.000, DG -0.06 +/- 0.04
lambda 0.000 - 0.000, DG  0.07 +/- 0.03
lambda 0.000 - 0.000, DG -0.08 +/- 0.02
lambda 0.000 - 0.000, DG  0.09 +/- 0.01
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/tmp$ mapfile -t a < <(sed '/lambda/s/.*DG *//' infile)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/tmp$ echo ${a[0]}
-0.00 +/- 0.00
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/tmp$ echo ${a[1]}
0.01 +/- 0.09
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/tmp$ echo ${a[2]}
-0.02 +/- 0.08
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/tmp$ for x in "${a[@]}"; do echo "$x"; done
-0.00 +/- 0.00
0.01 +/- 0.09
-0.02 +/- 0.08
0.03 +/- 0.07
-0.04 +/- 0.06
0.05 +/- 0.05
-0.06 +/- 0.04
0.07 +/- 0.03
-0.08 +/- 0.02
0.09 +/- 0.01
```

Comment: @VikasDubey You're welcome :)

Comment: @VikasDubey if this answer worked for you please consider accepting it by clicking the grey tick under the votes count; that's how you say that an answer worked for you; also, when you'll have more reputation,(15 or more) consider also upvoting the answers you accept along with any other useful answer you receive to your questions, and to any other useful answer you find while browsing the site; this is how the top answers rise to the top and the site works, nontheless is a way for crediting / giving reputation to the users who posted them. See also: http://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: @kos Hi, I have up-voted your answer. It very helpful. I have almost finished my program,  I just have a small glitch left. I have written  whole program in C. so, If I want to print say a[120]. I write  'system("echo ${a[120]}") ;' And I get an error "sh: 1: Bad substitution". I don't  know how to resolve this error. I will be grateful if you can help me with this .

Comment: @VikasDubey General programming stuff is off-topic here, so I won't ask you to add your C snippet to the question, which would make it off-topic, however I know C enough and I think I can help, but you should show me the full code. The error arises from the fact that `system()` is running the command in `dash`, which doesn't support arrays, but using `bash` should be adequately be integrated with the code if you want to use the results in the C program. Paste the code to [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the link here so I can take a look

Comment: @kos

Hi, I have pasted the necessary code , thanks for the interest.  
[link] (http://paste.ubuntu.com/12364273/)

Comment: @VikasDubey Fixed: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12364553/, I left some notes in the comments :)

Comment: @kos
You are great. It works fine. Thanks  a lot for the great help.

Comment: @VikasDubey: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**